# Elementary does not work with my RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller

Tags: networking, ethernet

Installation of latest version goes without problem but Ethernet is not showing up as available networking option.

Does Elementary support RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller at all?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, could you try connecting the machine to the internet via Ethernet over USB? This could be via adapter, directly from the router/modem, or tethering from a phone. Assuming this step works, fully update your system. The 5.4 kernel should include fixes for many RT devices. Once updated, make sure to restart, and if necessary, reconnect to Ethernet over USB and search for available drivers in AppCenter in the "Installed" tab or by using the `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` command.

Comment: Thank you for advice. Actually I swiped out Elementary on that partition to test other distro. After your message I did fresh install from the same  ISO as previously, with one difference - I had chosen "try" and run the update/upgrade having no idea if it affects tyhe installation at the end, but... After installation without "installing updates during installation" it booted with Ethernet working without issues. I don't know if the fact of update of the OS running from Live USB affected that, but it did apparently. Or, it was a coincident. BTW Live USB DID NOT see the Ethernet.